# How do I get my array from firebase to have the exact same output as my static array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

So I want to move my data from an array within my JS application into Firebase so i can easily update the values, however i'm having issues getting the value to return EXACTLY as it was when it was static. It needs to be identical since i'm looping over each of the `players`. I'm sure its something simple i'm missing but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

This is how i've structured my static array:

```js
// Team names and player IDs for each go here

const staticTeams = [
    {
        name: 'Byron',
        players: ["192", "278", "176", "172", "37", "335"]
    },
    //etc
];
```

This is how i'm fetching the Firebase data:

```js
async function getTeams(){
    let teams = []
    db.collection("teams").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            let data = doc.data();
            teams.push(data)
            // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    });
    return teams
  };
```

And i'm testing by printing to the console within another function like this:

```js
console.log("firebase", teams)
console.log("static", staticTeams)
```

Console outputs below:

```js
firebase 
[]
0: {name: "Mick", players: Array(6)}
1: {name: "Scott", players: Array(6)}
2: {name: "Moir", players: Array(6)}
3: {name: "Boyd", players: Array(6)}
4: {name: "Trev", players: Array(6)}
5: {name: "Tex", players: Array(6)}
6: {name: "Cail", players: Array(6)}
7: {name: "Byron", players: Array(6)}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)


static 
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Byron", players: Array(6)}
1: {name: "Moir", players: Array(6)}
2: {name: "Cail", players: Array(6)}
3: {name: "Boyd", players: Array(6)}
4: {name: "Mick", players: Array(6)}
5: {name: "Tex", players: Array(6)}
6: {name: "Trev", players: Array(6)}
7: {name: "Scott", players: Array(6)}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store an array of key-value-pairs that contains arrays as elements with a structure like this in Cloud Firestore:
[image]

Or if it has to be exactly the same structure you have now, it will look something like this:
[image]

To fetch the array from Firestore, you should do something like this:

```
db.collection("teams").doc("teamDocument").get().then(function(doc) {
        teams = doc.data().team; //this would be the array field
    });
```

Comment: Ah, that'll be it. I didn't set the top level to be array

Comment: I think the issue actually is that my static array is on "one line" and comma separated, but my firebase one is each team is on it's own line. Is something weird happening when i'm pushing the `doc.data();` into the teams array?

Comment: What do you mean by "on one line" and "on it's own line"? The data structure in your Firestore should now be the same as your static array, right?

Comment: When I print both to the console, the firebase version appears nested `firebase 
[]` and the static version appears to be comma separated `static 
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`.

Comment: What code are you using to fetch the data now? If you are using a similar code as before, you could be pushing the entire array into the array you are printing, which is why it appears nested

Comment: Same code as in the original question. If you're correct, any ideas on how to avoid doing that?

Comment: You shouldn't really use the same code if you are using my structure since it stores all the stuff in one document. (but the way you are using it is correct and should work) Instead, you should just reference the specific document and get that one document instead of the whole collection. Then, `doc.data()` returns the entire document reference, instead, you want the specific array field, so you need to reference that specific field like `doc.data().FIELD_NAME`, that will hopefully get you the array you wanted. Check my updated answer